Places on a commutative field
Let $K$ be a commutative field.
We define the notion of absolute value on field. We denote $M_K$ the set of places of the field $K$.
To simplify the notations, if $v$ is a place of $K$ we often write $| \cdot |_v$ the associated absolute value.
But there could be several absolute values ​​in the class of $v$.
My question is the following: what convention do we choose for the choice of the absolute value among all those of the equivalence class?

A place determines the valuation by choosing a prime $t$ of the place $P$ and then setting $v(a)=n$ if and only if $a=t^nu$ whereby $u\in\mathcal{O}_P^{\ast}$. It can be proved that it only depends on the choice of the place and not on the choice of the prime $t$. So it doesn't matter what prime you choose, that's the convention I guess.

At least in the case when $K$ is a global field (either an  algebraic number field or a function field of dimension one over a finite field), the choice of absolute value (in each equivalence class) is made so as to satisfy the product formula
$\prod_v |a|_v = 1$ (for any $a \in K^{*}$), where the product is taken over all absolute values (including the archimedean one(s) in case of characteristic zero), or over all non-archimedean absolute values in case of characteristic $p>0$.
That is why in the case of rationals, the choice of $p$-adic absolute value is $|a|_{v_p} = (1/p)^{v_p(a)}$ (where $v_p(a)$ is defined in the standard way for an element $a \in \mathbf{Q}$). Similarly, in the case for a number field $K$, the choice for the $\cal{P}$-adic absolute value is
$|a|_{v_{\cal{P}}} = (1/N(\cal{P}))^{v_{\cal{P}}(a)}$ (where $v_{\cal{P}}(a)$ is defined in the standard way for an element $a \in K$). (Here, the choice is for $\rho = 1/p$ (${\rm or}\ \rho = 1/N(\cal{P})$) over any other choice of real number $\rho$ such that $0 < \rho < 1$).
Edit: Similarly, in characteristic $p > 0$, for the case of $K = \mathbf{F}_q(x)$, the choice of $\rho$ is equal to $1/q^{{\rm deg}(f)}$ for the absolute value corresponding to the irreducible polynomial $f$ and the $f$-adic valuation $v_f$ (and $\rho = 1/q$ for the absolute value corresponding to the degree valuation $v_\infty$). One can verify that the product formula holds for such choice(s) of $\rho$. (And similarly, after some modification, when $K$ is a finite separable extension of $\mathbf{F}_q(x)$).

Another answer has pointed out the convenience of linking many inequivalent absolute values on a field $K$ if there is a product formula available, so I will not discuss that and instead consider just a single absolute value on $K$ up to equivalence.
Since equivalent absolute values on a field $K$ define the same topology on $K$ and have the same completion and the same open and closed unit balls in $K$ and in its completion with respect to those absolute values, it is largely irrelevant which one you pick if you are working only with a single absolute value up to equivalence.
However, Weil pointed out in his book "Basic Number Theory" that when $K$ is locally compact with respect to the topology given by an absolute value $|\cdot|$, we can use a Haar measure $\mu$ for that topology on $K$ to single out one choice among all absolute values equivalent to $|\cdot|$. To each $c \in K^\times$, $A \mapsto \mu(cA)$ is a measure on $K$, so it is a scalar multiple of the initial Haar measure $\mu$. Call that scaling factor $h(c)$:
$$
\mu(cA) = h(c)\mu(A)
$$
for all measurable subsets $A$ in $K$. It is not hard to see $h : K^\times \to \mathbf R_{>0}$ is multiplicative. Extend $h$ to $K$ by setting $h(0) = 0$. It turns out that $h$ on $K$ satisfies the triangle inequality when $K$ is totally disconnected, so $h$ is an absolute value on $K$.   When $K = \mathbf Q_p$, for example, $h(c)$ is the usual $p$-adic absolute value of $c$, namely $h(p) = 1/p$ rather than some other value between $0$ and $1$.
